# How do we use signal::filter and signal::butter in R for EEG data?

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, filtering, bandpass, eeg

I am trying to design an experiment to determine the peak amplitude of an EEG signal in response to a stimulus. Till now, our team has been using MATLAB and since we wish to go open source, we are trying to replicate the same in R.

- High pass cutoff: 0.3 Hz
- Low pass cutoff: 30 Hz
- Number of observations: 59000
- Sampling rate: 500 Sps

The code I have written is as follows:

```
#Trying to pass parameters as pi-radians
bf <- signal::butter(2,W=c(0.3,30)/250,type="pass",plane="s")

#test is my EEG dataframe in R
for (i in 2:9) {
  test[,i] <- signal::filter(bf,test[,i])
}
```

I tried following the example on stackoverflow:

[How do I run a high pass or low pass filter on data points in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105962/how-do-i-run-a-high-pass-or-low-pass-filter-on-data-points-in-r)

However, the amplitudes which I am getting via this is greatly different for the same set of parameters when using MATLAB's EEGLAB which uses `pop_basicfilter.m`.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Does the shape look similar though? Implementations often differ in a constant scaling factor. You can also examine the spectrum of the signal before and after filtering to make sure your filter in R is indeed doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you want to use signal::filtfilt rather than signal::filter for the cut-offs you set to map on to the half-amplitude cut-off (otherwise, with the signal::filter function, these are the half-power cut-offs).

See my answer here for example code showing how to use the W parameter in signal::butter and double-check that your filter is working appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905340/9665680